# How do I find the season from the month + date? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I spent way to much time on this, I'm pretty new to python. If someone could help the get the season from the month, and day that would be great, in the current example I'm just trying to get the month working, but if anyone can assist with adding the days that would be great!

```
    month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
    day = int(input("Enter a day: "))

def season(month):
    if (month == "12" or month == "01" or month == "02" or month == "03"):
        return "winter"
        
    elif(month == "04" or month == "05"):
        return "spring"
        
    elif(month =="06" or month=="07" or month == "08" or month == "09"):
        return "summer"
        
    elif(month =="10" or month=="11"):
        
        else:
            
        return "fall"
```

Comment: If you are converting the user input to int then you need to use ints in the if statements, so get rid of the "" around 12, 01, 02 etc.

Comment: First: your else statement needs to be one tab left. Second: Do you want meteorological or astronomical seasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check every single possible value of `month`. Just do an inequality. As norie pointed out, your user inputs are converted to integers anyways so this works perfectly for you.

```py
month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
day = int(input("Enter a day: "))

def season(month):
    if (month == 12 or 1 <= month <= 4):
        return "winter"   
    elif (4 <= month <= 5):
        return "spring" 
    elif (6 <= month <= 9):
        return "summer"
    else:
        return "fall"
    
print(season(month))
```