# How do I fix this to make it show the season from a specific cut off date (21st after each season)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is How do I fix my code to make it show the correct season from a specific day (e.g: It shows Winter on December 19th, while I told it to show winter on the 21st).
And if you are wondering why you are seeing this twice its because I posted the same question on a different account accidentally.

```
month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
day = int(input("Enter a day: "))

def season(month, day):
    if (month == 12 or 1 <= month <= 4):          #months
        return "winter"
    elif(4 <= month <= 5):
        return "spring"
    elif(6 <= month <= 9):
        return "summer"
    elif(9 <= month <= 12):
        return "fall" 

    if month % 3 == 0 and day >= 21:        #days
        if season == "winter":
            season = "spring"
        elif season == "spring":
            season = "summer"
        elif season == "summer":
            season = "fall"
        else:
            return "winter"
```

Comment: Could you link to the other question then, so the community can resume where it left off with your same question?

Comment: What do you think `return` is doing? (assuming month must be in the range 1-12)

Comment: Oh I found [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66554768/how-do-i-find-the-season-from-the-month-date-python) by looking at your post history.  Both questions by the same account?  And it looks solved.  What am I missing?

Comment: The way to fix your code is to write a simple loop that calls `season()` with 365 different days and print.  That would be a simple test suite, and I hazard that would not only fix your current problem but also provide assurance that it works for all days of the year.

Comment: I'm not sure what the other answer which arrived 20min after mine added that you picked that answer.  I already pointed out your 2 mistakes and provided a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand that with given day and season you want to determine the season according to that calender:

**Spring**: 21 March to 20 June

**Summer**: 21 June to 20 September

**Fall**: 21 September to 20 December

**Winter**: 21 December to 20 March

Your code was really close to that but you had a few problems:

- The seasons in your if conditions wasnt well defined.
- After checking the months you returned the result, so the day wasn't taked in consideration

Your code after a few changes:

```
def season(month, day):
    res = ""
    if (1 <= month <= 3):  # months
        res = "winter"
    elif (4 <= month <= 6):
        res = "spring"
    elif (7 <= month <= 9):
        res = "summer"
    elif (10 <= month <= 12):
        res = "fall"
    if month % 3 == 0 and day >= 21:  # days
        if res == "winter":
            return "spring"
        elif res == "spring":
            return "summer"
        elif res == "summer":
            return "fall"
        else:
            return "winter"
    return res
```

After the function call it like that:

```
month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
day = int(input("Enter a day: "))
print(season(month, day))
```

Comment: You need to call call this function with your day and month like in the main ill edit in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with your solution.  What you might find is that an appropriate data structure can do a lot of the heavy lifting for us.  Also, there are a couple bugs that I see.

1. The `if month % 3` statement only does `return` on the `else` case.  What happens in the other cases?  `None` is returned.  I think you want to set `season` and then `return season`.
2. But you just overloaded the variable `season` with the function `season()`.  Be careful of this pitfall.

I suggest to use a `dict` indexed by a `tuple` of `month` and `day`.  Essentially, creating a compound index.  This works because `tuple` is immutable, therefore hashable, therefore can be used as key in `dict` and elsewhere.

I also hope to show you how easy it is to have the computer generate test data for you, like I did below to verify my code works.

```
def season(month, day):
    SEASONS = {  # must be ordered descending like this
        (11, 21): "winter",
        (8, 21): "fall",
        (5, 21): "summer",
        (2, 21): "spring",
        (1, 1): "winter"
    }
    for k in SEASONS:
        if (month, day) >= k:
            return SEASONS[k]

res = []
for month in range(1, 13): # 1 through 12
    for day in range(1, 32): # 1 through 31
        result = season(month, day)
        res.append([month, day, result])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(res, width=120)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 'winter'],
 [1, 2, 'winter'],
 [1, 3, 'winter'],
...
 [3, 19, 'winter'],
 [3, 20, 'winter'],
 [3, 21, 'spring'],
...
 [6, 20, 'spring'],
 [6, 21, 'summer'],
 [6, 22, 'summer'],
...
 [9, 20, 'summer'],
 [9, 21, 'fall'],
...
 [12, 20, 'fall'],
 [12, 21, 'winter'],
...
 [12, 30, 'winter'],
 [12, 31, 'winter']]
```